# These credentials do not match our records login de laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estoy creando un login personalizado de Laravel pero siempre me retorna el error These credentials do not match our records login de laravel. Me he creado un nuevo controlador y modelo
LoginController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/';
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
    public function index(){
        return view('login.login');
    }
    public function username()
    {
        return 'usuario';
    }
}
```

Mi código del modelo Usuario:

```
namespace App;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class Usuario extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $remember_token = false;
    protected $fillable = ['usuario','password','estatus','id_rol'];
    protected $guarded = ['id_usuario'];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    public $timestamps = false;
    public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = \Hash::make($password);
    }
}
```

Ya he registrado el modelo en los providers de config-Auth.
También me cree un seeder para insertar el el usuario y el password con bcrypt. Aunque ingrese los datos correctos en el login me sigue retornando ese error.

Comment: La tabla personalizada se llama 'usuarios'?

Comment: Si, mi tabla se llama usuarios, la llave primaria se llama id_usuario

Comment: puedes ver en la tabla de la BD si el password se guardó encriptado?

Answer (score 0):

Regresa al modelo anterior de `User`, pero agrega una propiedad para determinar el nombre de la tabla

```
protected $table = 'usuarios';

//El resto de las configuraciones las puedes dejar como las tienes
protected $remember_token = false;
protected $fillable = ['usuario','password','estatus','id_rol'];
protected $guarded = ['id_usuario'];
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
public $timestamps = false;
```

Comment: Me sigue apareciendo el mismo error